# How to call a function in node js from react component - BFF

Tags: node.js, reactjs, micro-frontend

I've got a micro-frontend with a backend.
Project structure,

```
-app
--frontend
--- react components
---- componentA 

--server
--- (nodeJS) services
---- serviceA
```

What's the best way to call serviceA from componentA? without Rest/GraphQL?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run react app and nodejs server separately then you can use axios in react to call the endpoint exposed via nodejs server. Method calling isn't possible to the extent I know.